# JAXB schema compiler (XJC)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I have generated classes from xsd schema file through JAXB schema
compiler (XJC). Now I want to generate xml file from java classes.
please help me if anyone know about it.

Answer (score 2):

On the web, look for a JAXB tutorial. Also, consult the Javadoc for the classes in javax.xml.bind; it contains the essentials.

Code as shown below can be all you need, but it isn't necessarily exactly that what you'll have to use. See the indicated references for technical details.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( PACKAGE );
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
JAXBElement<Bar> jbe = objectFactory.createFoo(bar);
m.marshal( jbe, System.out );
```

Foo, bar and PACKAGE depend on your app.